# Error sending data with Ajax and receiving in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am sending Json data but when I verify my method in my controller it arrives as null

html:

```
<div class="hijo">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Proyecto, new { @class = "", style = "color:#040404" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ProyectoID, Model.Proyecto, "Seleccionar")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Proyecto, null, new { @class = "label label-danger", id = "Proyecto" })
                </div>
<div class="hijo">
                    <input type="button" id="adicionar" value="Agregar" class="myButton">
                </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#adicionar').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var data= {
        Proyecto: $("#ProyectoID option:selected").text()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "../ManejoDatos",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",  
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (mydata) {
            $("#UpdateDiv").html(mydata);
            history.pushState('', 'New URL: ' + href, href); // This Code lets you to change url howyouwant
        }
    });
 }
```

My Controller

```
public JsonResult ManejoDatos(string Proyecto)
    {
         ........
         ...
        return Json(Proyecto);
    }
```

Console

[image]

I don't know if it's something very simple to fix but I don't see the error

regards

Comment: Does it hit your controller?

Comment: In the controller it arrives as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your `JavaScript` code is absolutely fine. The weird things is controller with your format ghostly doesn't work But I got success below way:

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage ManejoDatos(string Proyecto)
        {
            var data = " my test data ";
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        }
```

I will investigate that obviously and update the answer again .

Hope above idea help you to resolve your problem. Let me know if you encounter any more problem.

Comment: Already try to send the value `Project:" Test "` but if getting null to the controller

Comment: Could you share your `HTML` specially `#adicionar ` class

Comment: Ready edit the question by adding where the data comes from

Comment: I have noticed, finding the problem

Comment: Add a photo of the console

Comment: I had already made that change as you mentioned but I still receive null :(

Comment: Wait I am checking

Comment: This is absolutely weird! When I tried   `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(string Proyecto )` I got data but `public JsonResult ManejoDatos(string Proyecto)` doesn't I am at a loss!

Comment: error in: Request.CreateResponse (HttpStatusCode.OK, data);

Answer (score 0):

Simple types like `string,int,float` etc are to be fetched from query string in .Net framework where as complex types always fetched from body.

**Solution-1**

In this case .Net Framework is expecting string **Proyecto** from query parameters and you can call your API like this without making any change to your server side code

Note:Also you don't need to define key of the parameter (in http request) which is being defined as `[From Body]`. As total of one simple type can be passed using `[FromBody]` attribute which you can see below like this `=ProyectoValue`

```
POST ../ManejoDatos HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59353
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
=ProyectoValue
```

**Solution-2**

Or you can call your API by putting all your params in complex model and pass params through body instead of query parameters like this

**Complex Type Model**

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public string Proyecto{ get; set; }
    }
```

**API Code**

```
public JsonResult ManejoDatos(MyModel myModel)
    {
         //Access using mymodel.Proyecto
         ........
         ...
        return Json(mymodel.Proyecto);
    }
```

And now you can consume your API by passing paramters through body like this

```
POST ../ManejoDatos HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59353
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

proyecto=myproyecto
```

Comment: I have tried all the approach you have written here. But doesn't got worked. you could have a look.

Comment: Its hard to make you understand in comment I have tried `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public JsonResult NewRndMethod([FromBody]MyClass Name)
        {
            return Json(Name);
        }`

Comment: This `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewRndMethod([FromBody]MyClass Name)
        {
            return Json(Name);
        }`

Comment: `[HttpPost("[action]")]
        [Route("TestMethod")]
        [ActionName("TestMethod")]
        public ActionResult<myClass> TestMethod([FromBody]myClass param)
        {
            return param;

        }`

Comment: You dont need to use `[FromBody]` with complex type  as you have done with NewRndMethod. Consider changing it